# Auto Archiving exchange mail in Apple Mail

Tags: email, apple-mail

My Exchangebox is lately constantly hitting the roof of it's max size (200Mb).
Is there a way in AppleMail to have it archive mails in my exchange account automatically to a local inbox when a mail is older than X days? Something like this would be of great help since i don't like manually archiving (cumbersome) and deleteing mail (bad bad bad!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in AppleMail as i have found out, but you can download an app to do it for you, i use [eMessage](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/7860)

> eMessage Archive (eMA) automatically archives email messages from a variety of different email client applications. Features include:
>
> Automatic background processing, with the folders to be archived saved in each database
>
> Archived messages are removed from your active email database after being safely put into a FileMaker database
>
> Filters for archiving only messages older than a specified date.
>
> More filters for status, priority, and others
>
> Reply to archived mail via any supported email application, regardless of its origin.
>
> Email and newsgroup messages archived together, in the same database

Comment: Too bad it is no longer active and supported by the developers, i can see major issues coming in the future with this app but it might do. Thanks!